# How to upload an Android image to storage server

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to upload the image into server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477629/how-to-upload-the-image-into-server)

I'm building my Andriod app and so far everything is ok.
I need to upload an image (That captured by android cam) to a server.
My question is: There is storage servers that supplies API for uploading an image and recieve back the url of the image? or perhaps i will upload it to my own servlet and save it somewhere? how it need to be done?

Thanks in advance.

P.S: I searched for this issue a lot and didn't find solution for my problem.